# Setting delegates and team members for a user in Lync

Tags: lync, lync-2013, ucma

I'm trying to set up delegates and team members for a user using UCMA. I have found [this very useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752709/retrieve-call-forwarding-rules-of-a-lync-client-with-server-side-technologies-u) (that links to some answers) on how to set up call forwarding rules and how to set up simultaneous ring. One of the suggestion is to use `Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Collaboration.Routing` which at first glance has everything I'd need.

The problem however is that adding some addresses to Routing.Delegates adds them to the users delegates list, but they are not displayed in the Lync client (see attached picture).

After examining how the Lync client adds these people to the list in the picture, I found out that it's not publishing it via routing category, but using this XML:

```
<setDelegates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2007/09/sip/delegate-management" version="6">
    <delegate uri="sip:somebody@example.com" action="add"/>
</setDelegates>
```

Is there a way how I could publish this XML using UCMA? Or is there some other way for adding the people in the list?

Thanks for any suggestion.

[image: Empty delegates list as viewed by the user]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7c5aebc7-4ee9-4f7a-ba2b-d4dd97b66326/setting-delegates-and-team-members-for-a-user-using-ucma?forum=ucmanagedsdk)

The solution is to hand craft the response using `BeginSendMessage` in  `_userEndpoint.InnerEndpoint.BeginSendMessage`.